# 6 months visa for Germany from Philippines

Tags: visas, germany, europe, schengen-visas, filipino-citizens

My daughter lives in Germany and she is a Philippine citizen with a working permit for Germany. She has a child with a German citizen but they have trouble to fill the time until the child can join the daycare. As far as I understand you can only stay 3 months in Germany with several things to consider, they have to sign a paper declaring they will take care of all my costs like housing and I have to get a health insurance. This is not a problem for us.

Sadly the 3 months are not enough to take care of my granddaughter. Is there any possibility to stay for 6 months ? I am too old to qualify for a Au-Pair and it is somehow not the purpose of my stay.

Comment: You would have to apply for a **National visa** (Type D) with the invitation, which should state how long you wish to stay.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am sorry to ask, but is it realistic that it would get accepted ? Or is it just a option I have and it's very unlikely they would accept it. I know only the german representative can decide that but maybe someone has experience with that.

Comment: Since this a parent and all costs and insurance are being garantied, the local authority (that issues the invitation) would be the decision maker, who would then inform the consulate that they have no objection.

Comment: @HazyCosmic No, you are not likely to get a longer national visa just for the purpose of taking care of your grandchild. Be aware, that if it is too obvious that you are offered housing in exchange of taking care of the child, it may be considered as work, something you are not allowed to do at all.